# Access MongoDB from Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying out MongoDB, and I wondering what the best way of mapping data from MongoDB to Java is.

My use case is that I'm trying to store 100.000+ documents (say movie+actors information), and I want to store text and image data (small images, around 100kb-300kb)

- I've tried Morphia, but it seems to be quite dead.
- There is a fork of Morphia, but I cannot find any experiences with that
- I can do any data mapping by hand, but it seems like a lot of work, and I'm 'afraid' that I'll end up with something like Morphia again to make it easier for myself
- I now there's also Spring Data for MongoDB, but I haven't checked it out yet.

What is the best way to go forward? I have the following questions:

- Should I choose an ORM, or should I do the mapping myself? Movies seems to be quite structured, so I don't see why not to use an ORM.
- If I go for ORM, what are the benefits of choosing Spring Data over Morphia (besides that there seems to be no releases for Morphia in the last months), or are there any solutions I haven't thought of?
- And with the risk of asking a too broad question again: are there any other things I have to consider when storing/retrieving data? For example, should I make a collection for Movie and one for Actor, considering I want to search for both? Or should I combine the Actor and Movie relations into one document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SpringData MongoDB](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb) - it's by far the easiest way to map POJOs to documents. Could you give me a little info on your setup (IDE, build tools, etc) and I can point you to an example?

I just threw together a simple example and posted it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/dwelch2344/spring-data-mongo-demo). Take a look

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. I'm using MacOS, IntelliJ, Gradle, latest MongoDB.

Comment: @ErikPragt I don't have a lot of experience with IntelliJ and Gradle, but I just posted a simple demo built with Maven. You should be able to import it into IntelliJ and see how it works

Comment: wow, that's great, thanks! If I could accept your answer twice, I'd do it!

Comment: Btw, is it also possible to store bytes[] like this? (I guess that's the required datatype for storing data?)

Comment: Hah, thanks. Glad I could help :)   Good question; I'm not positive if bytes will play nice, but you could always encode the data (base64 maybe?) on the way in / out - but admittedly that is a bit hacky. If you need FS-ish support, I'd use their GridFS support. 

See http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.core.html#gridfs

Comment: I'm actually trying to use GridFS. My files will never be above 2mb, so I don't think I really need it. I'll try the byte[] first, if that fails, we'll see :)